# ldap_add: Insufficient access (50) when applying ppolicy.ldif file

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am trying to apply ppolicy.ldif using following command

```
ldapmodify -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -W -a -f ppolicy.ldif
```

But it gives me follwoing output

```
adding new entry "cn=ppolicy,cn=schema,cn=config"
ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)
```

Here is my olcDatabase\={1}hdb.ldif file contents

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}hdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcSuffix: dc=example,dc=com
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymou
 s auth by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write by * read
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
olcRootPW:: e1NTSEF9SnIwWUxHTkhCZmY0Zi95UllTVitaNXJEM1ZrQ3lXOU8=
olcDbCheckpoint: 512 30
olcDbConfig: {0}set_cachesize 0 2097152 0
olcDbConfig: {1}set_lk_max_objects 1500
olcDbConfig: {2}set_lk_max_locks 1500
olcDbConfig: {3}set_lk_max_lockers 1500
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
structuralObjectClass: olcHdbConfig
entryUUID: 9b4d7cb2-ffdb-1034-96d3-4b48bfbee864
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20151005183533Z
entryCSN: 20151005183533.242143Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20151005183533Z
```

Here are the contents of olcDatabase={0}config.ldif file

```
dn: olcDatabase={0}config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
olcDatabase: {0}config
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external
 ,cn=auth manage by * break
structuralObjectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
entryUUID: 9b4ce158-ffdb-1034-96cb-4b48bfbee864
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20151005183533Z
entryCSN: 20151005183533.238162Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20151005183533Z
```

I am unable to understand what's going wrong. i am using admin user which has access to all things according to documentation.

any help will be appreciable. 
thanks

Comment: That's the wrong database. You need to show the configuration for the confit database itself.

Comment: hi EJP! i have just edited the question to include config database contents as well.

Comment: Well there you are. You don't have write access to that database via the user you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f ppolicy.ldif`. I am no expert on LDAP, but you need access to "cn=config" and that requires highest access rights, hence your command failed and this one should work.